# Combine two different rows in single table using same table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

Consider a database table holding data like that:

| Id | UserId | IsCheckIn | DateTime | Image | AccountId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30356 | 60866 | 1 | 2020-12-19 12:17:17 | b622f3e0806f.jpg | 10017 |
| 30355 | 60866 | 0 | 2020-12-19 10:52:26 | b622f3e0806f.jpg | 10017 |
| 30354 | 60866 | 1 | 2020-12-19 10:51:02 | b622f3e0806f.jpg | 10017 |
| 30353 | 60866 | 0 | 2020-01-20 09:29:42 | 1596.jpg | 10017 |

Desired output :

| Id | UserId | IsCheckIn | InDateTime | InImage | AccountId | IsCheckOut | OutDateTime | OutImage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30356 | 60866 | 1 | 2020-12-19 12:17:17 | b622f3e0806f.jpg | 10017 | 0 | 2020-12-19 10:52:26 | b622f3e0806f.jpg |
| 30354 | 60866 | 1 | 2020-12-19 10:51:02 | b622f3e0806f.jpg | 10017 | 0 | 2020-01-20 09:29:42 | 1596.jpg |

Please help

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If checkins and checkouts always properly interleave, you can use `lead()`:

```
select id, userid, ischeckin, 
    datetime as indatetime, image as inimage,
    accountid,
    lead_datetime as outdatetime, lead_image as outimage
from (
    select t.*,
        lead(datetime) over(partition by userid, accountid order by datetime) as lead_datetime,
        lead(image)    over(partition by userid, accountid order by datetime) as lead_image
    from mytable t
) t
where ischeckin = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're looking for something like this

```
select t.*, oa.*
from tTable t
     outer apply (select top(1) tt.[DateTime] OutDateTime, tt.[Image]
                  from tTable tt
                  where tt.IsCheckIn=0
                        and t.[DateTime]<tt.[DateTime]
                  order by tt.[DateTime]) oa
where IsCheckIn=1;
```